# dpkg: --dry-run does not check dependency?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

The following practice indicates that "dpkg --dry-run" does not perform dependency checking, or at least I don't know how to do it. If I want to make sure dependency is clear before installing package, what should I do? Thanks a lot for the help.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i --dry-run bsdgames_2.17-21_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 120870 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace bsdgames 2.17-21 (using bsdgames_2.17-21_amd64.deb) ...

$ echo $?
0

$ sudo dpkg -i bsdgames_2.17-21_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 120870 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace bsdgames 2.17-21 (using bsdgames_2.17-21_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement bsdgames ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bsdgames:
 bsdgames depends on wamerican | wordlist; however:
  Package wamerican is not installed.
  Package wordlist is not installed.
dpkg: error processing bsdgames (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bsdgames
```

## Clarification

I don't want dpkg to install dependencies for me. I only want some command to check dependency of the package. If the command returns 0, that means the current system has all the depending packages. This is all I need.

Answer (score 4):

*dpkg* doesn'not have dependency support. You have two choises;

1- use *gdebi* with

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
```

*gdebi* install deb package and their dependency.

```
sudo gdebi package.deb
```

2- After `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` you should run,

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Is it "common practice" to run `apt-get -f install` after running `dpkg -i *.deb` - after every run or just on failure?  I am trying to install .debs that are local files and not in a repository and `dpkg` is failing to meet the dependencies.  So, if I run `apt-get` afterwards, will it find the local .deb. package (it is there, it's just that the dependencies aren't being installed correctly using `dpkg -i`) or will it only try the repos that are configured in `sources.list`?